# How can I transfer Solana from several different wallets to one wallet in a single tx?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions, raydium

How can I transfer Solana from several different wallets to one wallet in a single tx?

I prefer web3.js if you have the code for that.

also I am hiring so write your Discord below if you know the answer to problems like this.